# The limit of a sequence when at $n-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Suppose $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is a series that converges.

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} S_n$ exists, where $S_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms of the series.

So, let $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} S_n = L$.

How do I formally justify that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} S_{n-1} = L$ too?

I think this is true because if we draw a number line and mark $L$ on it and $x_n$ as the sum of the first $n$ terms in the series, then as $n$ gets large, $x_n$ will get closer and closer to $L$. So, for really large values of $n$, $x_n$ will approach $L$ and so does $x_{n-1}$ too.

But I don't know how to show this mathematically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_n$ converges to $L$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that if $n > N$ then we have $|S_n - L| < \epsilon$.

The previous statement is also true for $N + 1$, hence for $n - 1 > N$.

EDIT: If a property holds for all $n > N$ then it holds for all $n > N+1$ necessarily, since if there exists $n_0 > N + 1$ such that the property (i.e. that $|S_{n_0} - L| < \epsilon$) does not hold, then (being $n_0 > N + 1$ and hence bigger than $N$) this would imply that the property was not true **for all** $n >N$. Is it clearer?

Also note that this is just a way to rewrite your intuition using the definition of limits

Comment: so I get $n-1 > N$ and $|S_{n-1} - L| < \epsilon$. Is that it?

Comment: I edited to make it more more clear, and it is exactly what you are saying :)

Comment: Now, if TBongers could take back his revenge -1, that would be great (in that case I would of course delete this comment)

Comment: okay. I don't understand what is going on. How can I be sure that the statement is also true for $N+1$? To me, all I did was just substituting symbols and I don't understand why I can do that.

Comment: I edited with more details, I hope it works for you now :)

Comment: thanks a lot. Almost got it. I am convinced that it will hold for $n > N+1$. I know that if $n > N+1$ is true, then $n-1 > N$ is true too. But I'm not sure why I can change the $n$ in $S_n$ to $S_{n-1}$ too (Other than just for the sake of making the $n$'s match.

Comment: Since the subindex $n$ is linked to the series $S_n$ here. You could consider $S_n$ as a function of n, such as $f(n) = S_n; f(n-1) = s_{n-1}$